# Short (?) story about immortality and end of mankind

Tags: story-identification, aliens, immortality, energy

I'm looking for a probably short story (but I'm not 100% sure about it) where mankind got this huge achievement (probably immortality but might have been energy) through killing an inferior alien species.

Because of that, some kind of galactic/space alien counsel decided to punish mankind by extermination, which led to a war. What I can clearly remember (and the reason I'm looking for it) was the ending, where a bunch of humans escaped with a very fast ship, chased by an alien one. The ships were so fast that they bent time, and in the end, as the universe was crunching, the aliens sent a message by asking humans to let them catch them so that the whole thing would make sense.

Comment: Sounds like something Alastair Reynolds would write.

Comment: Might be a slightly blurred recollection of [Stars, Won't You Hide Me?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133356/5930)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'd bet on it :-)

Comment: Pedro, you can read Ben Bova's story "Stars, Won't You Hide Me?" for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v03n05_1966-01_dtsg0318.Anon#page/n103/mode/2up). Please let us know if this is the story you're looking for.

Comment: Yes of course it was it <3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Stars, Won't You Hide Me?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54552) by Ben Bova

Mankind invents immortality but the raw ingredients come from the Flower People. For each human made immortal a flower person must die,

The Others decreed that mankind must become extinct for this crime. Especially since man did this once before. Then the Others were merciful and only blew man back into the stone age.

After the Last Battle, the sole surviving man runs away in a Bussard Ram jet starship being chased by one of the Others. It tells the man to surrender but he defies it

Due to time dilation the race ends in a draw as the universe dies in the Big Crunch