# Short Story About a Race to the End of Time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short story that I read years ago.  It is about the lone human survivor of a battle between aliens and humans.  The aliens are chasing him to eliminate humans entirely, going faster and faster.  His goal is to survive to the end of time, so that a human survives to the end.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please take a look at our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your post with any other information you remember.

Comment: Time dilation with slower-than-light starships?  This comes up every so often.

Comment: Is it the restaurant at the end of the universe by Douglas Adams?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Likely Ben Bova's "[Stars Won't You Hide Me?](https://www.robertraymond.com/stars-wont-you-hide-me-review/)" as per ["Not with a whimper, but with a roar of triumph!"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/not-with-a-whimper-but-with-a-roar-of-triumph), available to read online [here](https://archive.org/details/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v03n05_1966-01_dtsg0318.Anon/page/n103/mode/2up?view=theater).

> We start with Holman, a fellow wired up to a damaged star ship, racing away from the debacle of a battle where Humanity just lost to the Others. All we know about the Others is that they skirmished with humans once, put us back into the stone age, capped us with an artificial ice age to slow us down, then left us. But this time we’ve swarmed over the entire universe (spanning across billions of galaxies). We’ve figured out immortality  and, standing at the edge of godliness, get ready for that last push to that higher meadow of human happiness. But then the Others came.
>
> And in the mega-battle way out in the vast, they creamed us.
>
> So Holman runs – the Others following but unable to catch him, not yet. Using his sleep-couch, he is able to span the countless years as he run, hopping galaxy to galaxy, not sure where he is going. His ship, a meddler, roots through his thoughts and angles him home. Back to Earth, the seat of his race.
>
> Only to find it gone – stripped away, a cinder, the sun a small white sphere in it’s dead sky.
>
> And that’s the rub – if you are going to  go unimaginable distances, unless you have that kiddy-jumps of StarWars, it takes time. Buckets of time. Billions of years of time. So while he was away fighting the Others, the sun has expanded and devoured the Earth.
>
> And so he runs and runs and runs, the Others following him while around him, the blackness of space takes on a certain “gray” aspect.

The spaceship is programmed to prioritize humanity's survival, and therefore doesn't even give him an option to stop running and give up, especially since he is the last human. It ends with the Big Crunch.

> The galaxies were clustering in now, falling in together as though sliding down some titanic, invisible slope. The universe had stopped expanding eons ago, Holman now realized. Now it was contracting, pulling together again. It was all ending!
>
> He laughed. Coming to an end. Mankind and the Others, together, coming to the ultimate and complete end of everything.